# VB.net Index to text

Tags: vb.net

**Hello Good day to everyone.**

I am trying to explain my problem such as i can.
I have a text in a label (create user admin test) and I know that admin is (index) is 12.
I would need a help that how i can reed it back into a label. But (admin) it can be changed and the index stay same.
I have no idea where to start.
Here is my code for reed the index

```
Dim Str As String
    Str = TextBox1.Text
    Label1.Text = Str.IndexOf(TextBox2.Text)
    Label2.Text = Str.IndexOf(TextBox3.Text)
```

Basicly what i want to do if I give a text to a textbox and I am giving to another textbox an indext.
The program will give me back the text what is in that index.

Thanks any kind of help.

Comment: Unclear what problem you are facing.  What values are in TextBox2 and 3?  What should Label1 and Label2 have for output?

Comment: That part is only my converter to let me know the indexs.(Thanks for that i wil delet that part that makes no sense here.)
My problem is that I am puting this text to a textbox(Create user admin aa) and I want to know what text are in (INDEX = 12)

Comment: This is coming across as a XY problem.  You are asking about indexes, but I suspect you are trying to parse a command line "create user admin test" to perform a certain task.  Still unclear why you would care about index values.

Comment: One of my friend told me I can try like this. But If you have any other idea in this situation i become really happy.

Comment: I think it is a weird substring roundtrip thing with textboxes in place of vars.  The IndexOf admin is 12, so I think `Str.IndexOf` is hoped to get back admin from `12` and some other textbox text @LarsTech

Comment: i mean the admin text can be changed to anything but index remain same

Comment: Sorry, your question makes no sense at all.